# Showing previous and next pager links regardless of the page one is in

Tags: views, navigation, paging

Drupal hides the previous link  of a pager if you are the first page,and the next link if you are on the last page. Is there way I can keep the links from disappearing, just in a disabled state? Can I do this without using php?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, to do this you would have to use **theme_views_mini_pager()**.

**Reference:** http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21theme%21theme.inc/function/theme_views_mini_pager/7

**Example:**

```
if (empty($li_previous)) {
   $li_previous = "&nbsp;";
}
```

That is whats doing it...

Answer (score 1):

No - not without PHP, not without overriding the pager template in Views to do this. You could be able to do this in CSS if the views pager rendered the links but did not display them but the template excludes them. If you're willing to try creating a custom pager template, [this article](http://www.cyber-sundae.com/create-custom-pager-view-drupal-7-howto) explains the basic steps.

Comment: The link is dead.